# bash_profile Powerline setup

Tags: terminal, powerline

I am learning the command line and trying to customize my environment to have Powerline functionality.

I have installed the `Powerline` file from GitHub and am trying to add to my path variable.

My `.bash_profile` is set as follows:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/binpowerline-daemon -qPOWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1. /Users/johnmyers/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
```

I receive the following error messages when launching terminal.

> -bash: export: `-qPOWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1': not a valid
>   identifier
>
> -bash: export: `/Users/johnmyers/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh':
>   not a valid identifier

I would appreciate any guidance in the right direction on this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The stuff you added needs to be broken up on individual lines with newlines between them. I can only guess where the newlines are supposed to go, but something like

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin
# No need to repeat this
# export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin
powerline-daemon -q
POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1
POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1
. /Users/johnmyers/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
```